# java: Graphics2D version of polyline?

Tags: java, graphics2d

OK, so there's a `Line2D` and a `Rectangle2D` that can be used by [`Graphics2D.draw()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw%28java.awt.Shape%29) instead of `Graphics.drawLine()` and `Graphics.drawRectangle()`.

Is there a similar "upgrade" for `Graphics.drawPolyLine()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [`Path2D`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html). It is a `Shape` and should thus be able to be drawn through `Graphics2D.draw()`.

Example usage:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTestBase extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FrameTestBase t = new FrameTestBase();
        t.add(new JComponent() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Path2D p = new Path2D.Double();
                p.moveTo(15, 15);
                p.lineTo(150, 75);
                p.lineTo(100, 10);
                p.lineTo(10, 100);

                ((Graphics2D) g).draw(p);
            }
        });

        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.setSize(200, 200);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, it was you that asked ;-) (would perhaps not have provided "sample code" if I had noticed that it was you :)

Comment: doesn't matter whether or not it's me -- it's a better answer & helpful for everybody (& I'm a beginner in Java 2D graphics)